# How to mapping to exists object?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson

I have method "update" from CRUD controller:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(
        @PathVariable("id") Long id,
        @RequestBody Entity entity
) {
    repository.saveAndFlush(entity);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(entity);
}
```

This is code create new instance of entity.
How to map RequestBody to exist entity? Something like:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> update(
        @RequestBody @LoadById(@PathVariable("id")) Entity entity
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't as a PUT and POST should contain all the data needed to (re)construct the entity. If that isn't the case you would have to write your own HttpMessageConverter to enable this.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(
        @PathVariable("id") Long id,
        @Valid @RequestBody Entity entity
) {
    Entity oldEntity = repository.findOne(id);

    AnnotatedClass annotatedClass = AnnotatedClass.construct(
            entity.getClass(),
            objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().getAnnotationIntrospector(),
            new SimpleMixInResolver(null)
    );

    Iterator<AnnotatedField> fields = annotatedClass.fields().iterator();
    while (fields.hasNext()) {
        AnnotatedField field = fields.next();
        if (!objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().getAnnotationIntrospector().hasIgnoreMarker(field)) {
            field.fixAccess();
            field.setValue(oldEntity, field.getValue(entity));
        }
    }

    repository->save(oldEntity);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(oldEntity);
}
```